# LUIS: Can't add phrase list to my app

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, azure-language-understanding

I can't add phrase list to my app. The save button is not highlighting, although I am separating the entities by commas.

[image: screenshot]

What is the required field 'APP.FEATURE.PHRASELIST.MODAL.ADD.LABEL'?

Comment: Can you do a hard refresh? Ctrl+F5 if using Chrome? I think this might solve your problems... It should at least remove the APP.FEATURE.etc

Comment: did you ever find a solution? I have the same problem

Comment: Did you try pushing enter while having the cursor on the text box with the values?